# How to get real table filed name with JOOQ Field?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to get table filed real name by JOOQ Field, contains table name and field name.
I use the following two methods,

```
BOOK.TITLE.getName(); // title   it doesn't contains table name
BOOK.TITLE.toString(); // dev.book.title   it contains schema name
```

how to get `book.title` by JOOQ Field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generated fields implement [`TableField`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/TableField.html), which has a [`TableField.getTable()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/TableField.html#getTable()) method.

Another approach would be to call [`Field.getQualifiedName()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Named.html#getQualifiedName()) and then call [`Name.qualifier()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Name.html#qualifier()) to get the (again) qualified name of the table, if your field is [`Name.qualified()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Name.html#qualified()).